# Three.js 3rd person camera

Tags: camera, rotation, three.js

I'm trying to create a 3rd person camera view in three.js

I'm using the THREE.FirstPersonControls(); on my camera. Then setting the rotation and positions of my "player" objects to be the same as the camera with some offsets.

This does not seem to work.

What i'm more wondering is if I should be adding my FirstPersonControls to the camera and then rendering the "player" infront of it. Or adding the controls to the player then making the camera always point at the back of the player?

EDIT:

I've tried setting the player object to be a sub object of the camera using camera.add(player);

but moving the camera around is not moving the player. I thought adding an child element would mean they move together?

EDIT 2:

I took another approach of adding both the camera and the player to a group then adding my 1st person controls to that group... Now both the camera and the player do get rendered. But it's completely thrown off how the first person controls worked. (e.g. looking down goes left etc etc)

Thanks for any help,

James

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the Controls were designed to be controlling a *camera*, and not an object. And since by default, objects look "up" the z-axis, and cameras look "down" the z-axis, it is unlikely that the Controls will work as expected when applied to something other than a camera.

Secondly, the Controls are part of the examples, and not the library, so they are not officially supported. You are free to hack away at them.

One way to achieve what you want is to make the camera a child of your player. Something like this:

```
player.add( camera );
camera.position.set( 0, 50, 100 );
```

You may, in your render loop, need to set:

```
camera.lookAt( player.position );
```

Then you want to control the *player* with the mouse or keyboard. Your best bet is to write your own controller to do that. There are plenty of examples on the net.

Comment: thanks for the help, is there a reason why if I add a player to the camera it wouldn't work? What I wanted to do was set the player as a child of camera. Then if I offset the player to be in front of the camera, shouldn't that mean as I rotate the camera wouldn't the player move relative to it? 
Though I would need some way to set the rotation point to be at the camera?

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes", but if your are still having problems, please post a new issue along with a live example, or at a minimum, a code listing.